# How can I align showframe and header?

Tags: header-footer

When I use showframe in the geometry package, then the header "lines" lie not exactly on the header. Is there a way to align them perfectly with the header? I want to do that, to set the exact header distance from the top edge of the page.

Here's an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tI4a.jpg

Comment: I think you can't in a natural way:  the header line has a `height` and a `depth`, like all lines (because some letters have descenders). `\headheight` denotes the sum of both. Of course you can artificially obtain what you want with something like a `\raisebox{-0.3\basekineskip} {…}`.

Comment: Anyway, the point of showframes is to make sure you are not going outside the lines.  It also helps to check centering.